# Json to Javascript object or Array

Tags: javascript, django, json, datatables

I am developing a site on Django framework which returns a json response to be used jquery datatable. Datatable requires input to be either javascript object or array of arrys so i need to convert this on either server side or client side to javascript object or array.

Here is the related documentation for the datatable.

[DataTables AJAX source example](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/ajax/ajax.html)
[DataTables AJAX source example - array of objects as a data source](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/ajax/objects.html)

```
[
    {
        "pk": 7,
        "model": "softwareapp.software",
        "fields": {
            "city": "miami",
            "submitted_by": [],
            "description": "test",
            "title": "test",
            "zipcode": "test",
            "rating_votes": 0,
            "state": "fl",
            "address": "test",
            "rating_score": 0,
            "business_size": [
                5
            ],
            "slug": "test",
            "developer": "test"
        }
    },
    {
        "pk": 8,
        "model": "softwareapp.software",
        "fields": {
            "city": "",
            "submitted_by": [],
            "description": "",
            "title": "test2",
            "zipcode": "",
            "rating_votes": 0,
            "state": "",
            "address": "",
            "rating_score": 0,
            "business_size": [
                5
            ],
            "slug": "test2",
            "developer": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "pk": 10,
        "model": "softwareapp.software",
        "fields": {
            "city": "",
            "submitted_by": [],
            "description": "",
            "title": "test3",
            "zipcode": "",
            "rating_votes": 0,
            "state": "",
            "address": "",
            "rating_score": 0,
            "business_size": [
                6
            ],
            "slug": "test3",
            "developer": ""
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Google "Json to Javascript object" click on the first link.

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers support [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), which is defined in ECMA-262 5th Edition (the specification that JS is based on). Its usage is simple:

```
var json = '{"result":true,"count":1}',
obj = JSON.parse(json);

alert(obj.count);
```

For the browsers that don't you can implement it using [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js).

Answer (score 0):

On the client you could use:

```
JSON.parse(json)
```

"json" being the JSON string .

Or if you're also using jQuery to do the AJAX request it will do the deserialization for you in the "success" handler.

```
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "your url",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (e) {
           // the value of "e" should be a javascript object or array depending on the    response

        }
    });
```